# How to upload dataset into Google cloud platform? How to deal with datatypes?

Tags: google-bigquery

While uploading my dataset from Google drive to Google cloud platform, I failed to edit the schema. Every time I  uploaded the dataset, I was asked to edit the schema. For example, column: yearinjob was in the type of float. But while executing the query SELECT * FROM ...
it always says Error while reading the table: XXX.demo1.wkfc3, error message: Could not convert the value to float. Row 1888; Col 19.

I changed the schema for a datatype to integer, numeric, but none works except string.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: I'm wondering what is in Row 1888; Col 19.

Comment: for me dataset, it's the year in jobs data, e.g 1.1, 1.2 in years. Which means the time the employer worked for the company. However, the BigQuery doesn't allow the transfer from value to float. I later changed it to string, then it works. But for future calculation, it is a big trouble.

Comment: Can you share more info about your schema? Have you verified that your Dataset is already updated when you are trying the SELECT statement? It seems that the issue is related with the update of the Dataset, the Data types are not the same as the schema.

Comment: While uploading the data, seems we should verify the schema first. Until I edited all the schema to meet the standard I could finally import the data to project as the data source. I don't know why BigQuery cannot automatically recognize the schema, esp the data type itself. I have change datatype again and again by uploading the dataset from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might ensure that **the info in the dataset that you are uploading is aligned to your [Specified Schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas).**

When you use [Schema auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#auto-detect), BigQuery starts the inference process by selecting a random file in the data source and scanning up to 100 rows of data to use as a representative sample. BigQuery then examines each field and attempts to assign a data type to that field based on the values in the sample.

**Check that the value at Row 1888; Col 19 matches with the assigned type for that field**. That might be the cause of the error “Could not convert the value to float”.

This docs that may be helpful.

1. This is the documentation for [Data Types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) and allowed values.
2. And this is about [managing datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets).